# Job offer, after Ceo Interview Hr is delaying to send in the offer letter

Tags: job-offer

I applied for a Position of client servicing in an Advertising agency. Company Head HR contacted me from a online Job portal.

I was interviewed by 3 fellow employees on 18th Jan 2017.

Post which I was contacted by 1 of them on 27th Feb 2017 for the final round with the CEO who is not in the city as the head office is in another city , as per my conversation with her I was supposed to update HR with my joining feasibility after which I would receive the offer.

I updated the HR on 28th Feb 2017 that I would be able to join immediately. I was asked to wait for a reply as the process would take time. Since the CEO is not in the city and to top it she is on a vacation out of station. A reasonable response for the HR wanted to discuss with CEO before making an offer to me.

I did make a follow up call to the HR on 8th March 2017 but again was asked to wait. To which I asked, How soon would I be informed and by which medium? 
ANS: I will get back to you don't worry but am unsure of the time that it will take. You will need to wait.

I was really looking forward to work with this company, but am unsure of the status of the interview procedure.

17th March 2017, the head HR who had contacted me from the online Job portal send me an interview request again.

I am confused what should I really do.

P.S : I have not been spoken to regarding salary at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: I can guess what is happening here. They are fishing for more resumes hoping to find a better candidate, but keeping you around as a "safety net" in case they don't find anyone. I have experienced way too often that an important decision maker conveniently "goes on vacation" around that time. That is just a stalling tactic. It just so happened that while fishing, they hit your resume again.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason this matters is if you're doing something you shouldn't be doing. **Never stop looking for a job, or decline interviews or offers, because someone has told you to expect an offer.** You've been told to pass along your availability date and expect an offer. That's great! Congratulations! Now keep right on doing what you've been doing. At some point, someone is going to give you an offer in writing that you want to accept. Then, **and only then**, you need to get in touch with any and all people who've given you verbal assurances and told you to expect things. You tell them:

> I have been expecting a written offer from your firm and look forward to accepting it when I do. In the meantime I now have a written offer from another firm. How quickly can you get me a written offer so that I can feel free to decline the one I just received?

Since you have no other written offer right now, you have no real need to keep poking these people and asking you when they will make you your offer. If you are quoting the actual replies you got from them, they sound a little irritated. Leave them alone until they contact you. Using the portal to set up another interview sounds like contacting you, so go ahead and set that up, it might be an interview to establish your salary and finalize everything before the written offer.

Answer (score 0):

Like so many things in business, this can be fixed with some polite but firm communication.

Immediately (even if it's a Saturday!) contact the head of HR and clarify if this is another interview request or if it's just a meeting to discuss employment terms like salary/vacation. We know it's because you're afraid they're sending you back for interviews. You'll tell them it's because you want to properly prepare for whatever meeting is coming up.

What you don't want to do is: whine, beg, be rude, be unprepared, be surprised, or walk away. You do want to be firm, polite, and flexible. By the way, that's good rules to live by in general, not just for this interview situation.